# ASP.NET Core React Template get access-token

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Is there a way to get the access token from identityserver4, preferably in the Login.cshtml.cs post function. I am using the default react with authentification template (asp.net core 3.1) from visual studio. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the issued tokens in Login.cshtml.cs post function .

That is because Asp.net Identity credential validation logic is fired before Identity Server's token issue logic . In `OnPostAsync` event of `Login.cshtml.cs` , the identity system will check user in database and sign in user using :

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

If user validation passed , it will redirect to local url like `/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=react&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44362%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=code&scope=reactAPI%20openid%20profile&state=xxxxx&code_challenge=xxxxx&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query` , that url in fact is OpenID Connect Authorzation Code Flow(PKCE) request . After redirecting , identity server 4 middleware will handle the code and token request and at last issue tokens . So that in `OnPostAsync` function you can't get the tokens .

If you want to get the tokens , you can get tokens from identity server's   [built-in events](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/stable/topics/events.html#built-in-events) like `TokenIssuedSuccessEvent` , you can also get tokens from React client side ,   in which event/place to get tokens is based on your requirement .